# Passing Arraylist to SQL query to get the desired result

Tags: java, sql, database, parameters, hql

I wrote a query like this:

```
select agent_id,count(id) as agentCount from demo.table lst where lst.agent_id in(:idpList) group by agent_id order by agentCount ASC;
```

but this only returns the agent_id which are in idp List i also want to get the ids that are in the list but not in demo.table and return count as 0 .
 i am not able to figure out how can i do that.

eg : List :  [20,17,16,15,50] so 50 is not the table but yet i want 50 to be included in the end result.

i have two DB from one i am getting all the agent_id and storing it in List
and in another DB i have table that stores the id and no of task associated with these id so i want to check how many times task has been created corresponding to these agent_id and get the count but as these some of agent_id are present in 2nd DB table but some are not so for the one that are not present count should return 0 but from this query i am getting the count of only those that are present in the second DB table

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u once share the output of this query?

Comment: for now the output of this query is 
agent_id        agentcount
20                  2
17                  3
16                  1
15                  1


but i want 50 also with the count 0

Comment: hello , your requirement is not clear , can you please try to restate the requirement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select count(*),A.agent_id from 
(
select 20 as agent_id
union select 17
union select 16
union select 15
union select 50 ) as A  LEFT JOIN demo.table s on s.agent_id = A.agent_id where s.agent_id in(:idpList)  group by s.agent_id;
```

But you have to create this part  (
    select 20 as agent_id
    union select 17
    union select 16
    union select 15
    union select 50 ) of query manually.

Otherwise there is no way to this.

Comment: but the list is dynamic and the size too

Comment: yes I know, it is dynamic, that why i have written in my answer to handle this manually,as per user dynamic just create the first part programmatically then take join as per my query.